# Flutter / Firebase / Json : Trying to save Latitude and Longitude data into Firestore

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save the latitude and longitude of a marker in the database.

Unfortunately I have this error:

> Invalid argument: Instance of 'LatLng'

Package : latlong2: ^0.9.0

My model:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

class ActivitiesModel {
  String id;
  String organisateur;
  final DateTime? createDate;
  final DateTime? modifyDate;
  LatLng location;

  ActivitiesModel({
    this.id = '',
    required this.organisateur,
    this.createDate,
    this.modifyDate,
    required this.location,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'organisateur': organisateur,
        'createDate': createDate,
        'modifyDate': modifyDate,
        'location': location,
      };

  static ActivitiesModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ActivitiesModel(
    id: json['id'],
    organisateur: json['organisateur'],
    createDate: (json['createDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
    modifyDate: (json['modifyDate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
    location: LatLng.fromJson(json['location']),
  );
}
```

The information location I try to save into Firebase Database:

```
final activitiesModel = ActivitiesModel(
  id: widget.activitiesModel.id,
  organisateur: 'Mickael R.',
  createDate: widget.activitiesModel.createDate,
  modifyDate: DateTime.now(),
  location: LatLng(-12.0080041, -77.0778237),
);
return activitiesModel;
```

This is the error I have:

> Invalid argument: Instance of 'LatLng'

How may I save my position in the Database using the object LatLng ?

Comment: I don't immediately see a call to the Firestore API in the code you shared. Which line is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you're passing an object of type `ActivitiesModel`, and it can't handle the `LatLng` field in there - as it can only handle the types documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Before you pass an object to Firestore, you need to ensure it only contains types from that documented list, including maps and arrays of those types.

So I'd typically store a lat/lon pair as either a map with named fields, or an array with two value.

Comment: Hello, 

Sorry for my late reply.
Thank you so much for your help.

I fixed it.